# sudo apt-get update fails with a temporary failure resolving sources

Tags: apt, updates, dns

I cannot update Ubuntu 20.04 since 2/11/2022. I am connected to the internet wirelessly, on a private network at my home. There is no proxy set up. My main OS is Windows 11.

I tried to update Ubuntu in VirtualBox and used WSL2 with the same result.

Pinging localhost works the same for the IP that is inside of `/etc/resolv.conf`

`sudo apt-get update`:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I can ping cat resolv.conf

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.23.224.1

 ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.216 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7279ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.044/0.076/0.216/0.055 ms
```

Comment: I don't understand how you are trying to update Ubuntu in both VirtualBox and WSL.  How and where is Ubuntu installed? It can't be both.

Comment: Do you have some firewall or antivirus installed?